# When is a stopped Brownian motion not a markov process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W_t,t\geq 0$  be a Brownian motion start from zero and $\tau$ a stopping time. For what kinds of $\tau$, $W_{t \wedge \tau}$ is not a markov process?

I have considered choices of constant stopping time, like $\tau=1$; and the hitting time, but they do not work well.

Comment: It's definitely a markov process. Why do you think it's not ?

Comment: The construction appears in a hint in my exercise, so I wonder if it exists. By the way, would you explain more about why it should be a Markov process?

Comment: Because of the strong Markov property.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so every stopped process with the original process having strong Markov property is Markov again? Is there a reference for that? From my understanding, the derived process will be $X_{\tau+t}$ instead of $X_{\tau\wedge t}$ if it is markov

Comment: Strong markov property says that if $\sigma \leq \tau<\infty  $ a.s., then  $\mathbb E[f(X_{\tau})\mid \mathcal F_\sigma ]=\mathbb E^{X_\sigma }[f(X_{\tau-\sigma })]$ for all bounded and borel $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

**Example:** How about $\tau:=\inf\{t>T_1: W_t=0\}$, where $T_1:=\inf\{t>0: W_t = 1\}$. In words, $\tau$ is the time of first return to state $0$ after the first visit to  state 1.

The process $X_t:=W_{t\wedge\tau}$ is certainly not a strong Markov process because state $0$ turns into a trap after the first visit to state $1$. It's not even a simple Markov process because for a bounded measurable $f$ and $0<s<t$,
$$
E[f(X_t)\mid\mathcal F^X_s]=1_{\{\tau\le s\}} f(0)+1_{\{\tau>s\}}h(X_s,t-s),
$$
where $h(x,u):=E^x[f(W_{u\wedge T_0})]$, $T_0$ is the hitting time of $0$ by $W$, and $E^x$ is expectation relative to the Brownian motion started at $x$. The above display shows that the conditional distribution of $X_t$, given the history up to time $s$, depends not just on $X_s$ but also on the event $\{\tau\le s\}$.

A stopping time $T$ of $W$ is called a *terminal time* if $T(\omega)=t+T(\theta_t\omega)$ for all $\omega$ in the event $\{t<T\}$, for each $t\ge 0$. Here $\theta_t$ is the shift operator acting on the sample space of the Brownian motion by $W_u(\theta_t\omega) = W_{u+t}(\omega)$. A hitting time like $T_A:=\inf\{t>0:W_t\in A\}$ is a terminal time. If $T$ is a terminal time then the stopped process $W_{t\wedge T}$ will be a Markov process.

Comment: Why the downvote?